# Why does Pycharm IDE show "Unresolved reference" to the shared object ".so" files created from .pyx files?

Tags: pycharm, shared-objects

I have built .pyx files into .so files and when I try to access the functions inside the .so file, PyCharm IDE always shows "Unresolved reference" and "Module not found" error. How should I import the .so files into python ? after building the .pyx files into .so files using a "setup.py" file, how should I import them into python ? Should I define the path of these files ?

After going through some posts on this topic, I tried 
1) adding the directory of these .so files into PYTHONPATH
2) adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in Pycharm project interpreter
3)running ldconfig -n path_to_the_files in Terminal

None of these are working and my IDE still doesn't detect the .so files